# laravel seeder doesn't perform condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-seeding

I'm trying to add a new boolean field to the areas table called "hasAddresses", it should be true if at least 1 address exists for this area, otherwise it should be false.

Problem - it changes all fields to true

```php
class AddhasAdressesSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $addressesareasIds=Address::get('areaId');
        $areas=Area::get();

        foreach ($areas as $area){
            $area=Area::get('id');
            $exists=Address::exists($addressesareasIds,$area);
            if($exists)
            DB::table('areas')->update([
                'hasAddresses' => true
            ]);
        }

    
    }
}
```

Comment: you may be looking for the whereExists to query the relationship https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-exists-clauses

Comment: If you have a relationship defined then your query can probably be simplified as `Area::has('address')->update([ 'hasAddresses' => true ])` instead of this entire code

Answer (score 1):

makesure you have a relation on your Area Model

```
//Area.php
public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Address::class);
    }
```

and then use this in your seeder

```
    {
        $areas=Area::whereHas("addresses")->update("hasAddresses",true);    
    }
```